# Rails: Error when trying to save a special character to database when using ActiveRecord and TinyTDS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parsing, character-encoding, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to save this character "É" as part of a string using ActiveRecord to my sql server using TinyTDS. Any idea on what I need to do to get rid of the following error?

```
Exiting
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-3.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver/database_statements.rb:387:in `execute': TinyTds::Error: Error converting characters into server's character set. Some character(s) could not be converted
```

The string I imagine it's erroring out on is the following: `JEREMÉ`

Below is my code I'm using to parse the file...

```
csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers=>false, encoding: "UTF-8")
csv.drop(2).each do |row|
    person = Person.new(:lastname => row[0], :firstname => row[1])
    playerstats.save
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
value = value.force_encoding('ISO-8859-1').encode('UTF-8')
```

This will make your string database happy.